# VueJs TypeError: "_vm.saveEmployee is not a function" on form submit

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vue-component

I'm coding a Employee Database in Vuejs using Firebase as my backend. On my new employee page I keep getting a 3 errors when submitting the form to add a new employee.

"Property or method "saveEmployee" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property."

"[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: _vm.saveEmployee is not a function"

"TypeError: "_vm.saveEmployee is not a function"

This is how my newemployee.vue file looks like

```
<template>
  <div id="new-employee">
    <h3>New Employee</h3>
    <div class="row">
      <form @submit.prevent="saveEmployee" class="col s12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input type="text" v-model="employee_id" required />
            <label>Employee ID#</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input type="text" v-model="name" required />
            <label>Name</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input type="text" v-model="dept" required />
            <label>Department</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input type="text" v-model="position" required />
            <label>Name</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
        <router-link to="/" class="btn grey">Cancel</router-link>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import db from "./firebaseInit";
export default {
  name: "new-employee",
  data() {
    return {
      employee_id: null,
      name: null,
      dept: null,
      position: null
    };
  },
  methods: {
    saveEmployee() {
      db.collection("employees")
        .add({
          employee_id: this.employee_id,
          name: this.name,
          dept: this.dept,
          position: this.position
        })
        .then(docRef => {
          console.log("Client added: ", docRef.id);
          this.$router.push("/");
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error("Error adding employee: ", error);
        });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

The whole problem is on the saveEmployee function and I can not find a fix.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code tho, better still add brackets  saveEmployee()

Comment: I added the brackets and it worked, not sure if this was the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Stay Cool!.. Support the comment, please.